# selenium: extract data to data frame based on a form name using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to extract the info from [this](http://imed.med.ucm.es/epimhc/) site into a pandas dataframe. This code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys
import re
import requests

options = Options()
options.binary_location=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
#options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='/mnt/c/Users/kela/Desktop/selenium/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('http://imed.med.ucm.es/epimhc/')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="mhc"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="seq"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="mhc_source"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="class"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="length"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="peptide_source"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="bind_level"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="epitope"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="epitope_level"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="reference"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="protein_name"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="protein_source"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value=Search]').click()
```

Brings me to the table that I want to convert to a pandas dataframe:

[image]

My issue is how to convert the table viewed on this page into a pandas dataframe.

I can see that the table I want has a form name = pepList. So I was trying something like:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[name = pepList]')
```

and similar options. Even if I am able to accurately identify the table, the rows in the table are an unusual format (compared to what I am used to):

[image]

If someone could demonstrate how to extract the table on this page into a pandas dataframe, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `pandas.read_html` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_html.html maybe this'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After click on the search button take the driver.`page_source`
Using pandas use `read_html()`

```
df=pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
print(df[1])
```

Your entire code like.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
options = Options()
options.binary_location=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
#options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='/mnt/c/Users/kela/Desktop/selenium/chromedriver.exe')


driver.get('http://imed.med.ucm.es/epimhc/')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="mhc"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="seq"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="mhc_source"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="class"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="length"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="peptide_source"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="bind_level"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="epitope"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="epitope_level"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="reference"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="protein_name"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="protein_source"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value=Search]').click()
df=pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
print(df[1])
```

Comment: @Slowat_Kela : Indeed you were.